# org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Config problem Failed to import bean definitions from [classpath:/beans.xml]

Tags: spring-mvc

I am a beginner working with Spring MVC. Compile runs successfully, but I get the following error while deploying on Apache tomcat 8.5

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:/beans.xml]
```

Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-servlet.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [beans.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Context namespace element 'component-scan' and its parser class [org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser] are only available on JDK 1.5 and higher
at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:76)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:182)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseDefaultElement(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:147)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:132)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:92)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:507)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:398)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:342)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:310)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:92)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:123)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:422)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:352)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4763)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5232)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1429)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [beans.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Context namespace element 'component-scan' and its parser class [org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser] are only available on JDK 1.5 and higher
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:420)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:342)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:310)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:174)
... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Context namespace element 'component-scan' and its parser class [org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser] are only available on JDK 1.5 and higher
at org.springframework.context.config.ContextNamespaceHandler$1.parse(ContextNamespaceHandler.java:65)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:69)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1297)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1287)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:135)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:92)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:507)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:398)
... 32 more

Please, find xml files below :

```
- web.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- web.xml -->
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
   <display-name>Mvc</display-name>
   <welcome-file-list>
      <welcome-file>connexion.jsp</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>
   <servlet>
      <description />
      <display-name>ConnexionServlet</display-name>
      <servlet-name>ConnexionServlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>com.springmvc.controller.ConnexionServlet</servlet-class>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
         <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-servlet.xml</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>ConnexionServlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/ConnexionServlet</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
   <servlet>
      <description />
      <display-name>DeconnexionServlet</display-name>
      <servlet-name>DeconnexionServlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>com.springmvc.controller.DeconnexionServlet</servlet-class>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>DeconnexionServlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/DeconnexionServlet</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
   <context-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-servlet.xml</param-value>
   </context-param>
   <listener>
      <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
   </listener>
</web-app>
```

```
- beans.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- beans.xml -->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
   <context:component-scan base-package="com.springmvc" />
   <context:annotation-config />
   <bean id="articleService" class="com.springmvc.service.ArticleServiceImpl" />
   <bean id="clientService" class="com.springmvc.service.ClientServiceImpl" />
   <bean id="commanderService" class="com.springmvc.service.CommanderServiceImpl" />
   <bean id="MySQLConnection" class="com.springmvc.service.MySQLConnection">
      <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
      <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase" />
      <property name="username" value="root" />
      <property name="password" value=" " />
   </bean>
   <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
      <!-- Maximum Upload Size (In Bytes) -->
      <property name="maxUploadSize" value="20971520" />
      <!-- Maximum Size Of The File In Memory (In Bytes) -->
      <property name="maxInMemorySize" value="1048576" />
   </bean>
</beans>
```

```
- spring-mvc-servlet.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- spring-mvc-servlet.xml -->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd  http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">
   <import resource="classpath:/beans.xml" />
   <context:component-scan base-package="com.springmvc" />
   <context:annotation-config />
   <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/theme/" cache-period="31556926" />
   <mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/images/" />
   <mvc:annotation-driven />
   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping" />
   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />
   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />
   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean>
</beans>
```

```
- pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- pom.xml -->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>Mvc</groupId>
   <artifactId>mvc</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <packaging>war</packaging>
   <name>Mvc Maven Webapp</name>
   <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
   <url>http://www.example.com</url>
   <properties>
      <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
      <spring.version>4.3.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
      <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
      <servlet.version>3.1.0</servlet.version>
      <servlet.version>3.0.1</servlet.version>
      <mysql.connector.version>5.1.9</mysql.connector.version>
      <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
      <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
   </properties>
   <dependencies>
      <!-- Junit -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>junit</groupId>
         <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
         <version>${junit.version}</version>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <!--Servlet-Api -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
         <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
         <version>${servlet.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- Spring Framework -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
         <version>${spring.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
         <version>${spring.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
         <version>${spring.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
         <version>${spring.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
         <version>${spring.version}</version>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
         <version>${spring.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- MySQL database driver -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>mysql</groupId>
         <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
         <version>${mysql.connector.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
         <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
         <version>2.0</version>
         <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
         <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
         <version>1.2</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
         <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
         <version>1.1.2</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- FileUpload dependency -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
         <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
         <version>1.4</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
         <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
         <version>2.5</version>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   <build>
      <finalName>passerel</finalName>
      <pluginManagement>
         <!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
         <plugins>
            <plugin>
               <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>3.1.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging -->
            <plugin>
               <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>3.0.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
               <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>3.8.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
               <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>2.22.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
               <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>3.2.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
               <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>2.5.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
               <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>2.8.2</version>
            </plugin>
         </plugins>
      </pluginManagement>
   </build>
</project>
```

[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtRRH.png)

Could you please help me ?
Regards,

Comment: Please help me.

Comment: I moved spring-mvc-servlet.xml to java/resources and getting now the error : org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-servlet.xml]